Not able to prevent unmounting of component
I am developing an application in which at a point I need to trigger a jenkins pipeline through code, when that pipeline is completed then a post request is send from pipeline sending the buil dnumber and response and when that request is recieved then another request to fetch megalinter logs has to be done.
This is governed by mounting and unmounting of a component but I don't know how the component is unmounted within a second and the execution stops and code is not running.
this is what coming in console log of browser

and this in server logs

I have tried many things including using React.memo to prevent re-renders and useRef but still nothing is happening
this is code
  const pipelineTriggered = useRef(false);
  const isMountedRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Effect running, repoName:', repoName);
    
    const runPipeline = async () => {
      if (pipelineTriggered.current) return;
      pipelineTriggered.current = true;

      try {
        console.log('Starting pipeline process');
        setBuildStage('Authenticating');
        
        console.log('Fetching user data from Supabase');
        const { data: { user }, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
        if (error) throw new Error('Failed to fetch user data');
        
        const githubUsername = user.user_metadata.user_name;
        if (!githubUsername) throw new Error('GitHub username not found in user metadata');

        console.log('User authenticated, triggering pipeline');
        setBuildStage('Triggering Pipeline');
        const response = await axios.post('/api/trigger-pipeline', { repoName, githubUsername });
        console.log('Pipeline trigger response:', response.data);

        if (!isMountedRef.current) {
          console.log('Component unmounted, stopping execution');
          return;
        }

        console.log('Setting build stage to Waiting for Build');
        setBuildStage('Waiting for Build');

        const pollBuildStatus = async () => {
          while (isMountedRef.current) {
            try {
              const { data: buildStatus } = await axios.get('/api/build-status');
              console.log('Build status:', buildStatus);
              
              if (!buildStatus.building) {
                if (buildStatus.result === 'SUCCESS') {
                  setBuildStage('Fetching Results');
                  const { data: megaLinterLog } = await axios.get(`/api/megalinter-logs/${buildStatus.number}`);
                  processMegaLinterResults(megaLinterLog);
                  setBuildStage('Complete');
                } else {
                  setBuildStage('Build Failed');
                }
                break;
              }
              await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // Wait 5 seconds before polling again
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error checking build status:', error);
              await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
            }
          }
        };

        pollBuildStatus();

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in pipeline process:', error);
        if (isMountedRef.current) {
          setBuildStage('Failed');
        }
      }
    };

    runPipeline();

    return () => {
      console.log('Cleanup function called, setting isMounted to false');
      isMountedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, [repoName]);

 <div className="p-4 flex-grow">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Issues of {repoName}</h1>
        {buildStage !== 'Complete' ? (
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-64">
            <div className="loader"></div>
            <p className="mt-4">Build in progress: {buildStage}</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <select onChange={(e) => handleFilterChange('severity', e.target.value)} value={filters.severity}>
                <option value="">All Severities</option>
                {/* Add severity options */}
              </select>
              <select onChange={(e) => handleFilterChange('language', e.target.value)} value={filters.language}>
                <option value="">All Languages</option>
                {/* Add language options */}
              </select>
              <select onChange={(e) => handleFilterChange('linter', e.target.value)} value={filters.linter}>
                <option value="">All Linters</option>
                {/* Add linter options */}
              </select>
            </div>
            <table className="min-w-full bg-white">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="py-2 px-4 border-b">S.No</th>
                  <th className="py-2 px-4 border-b">Issues</th>
                  <th className="py-2 px-4 border-b">Linter</th>
                  <th className="py-2 px-4 border-b">File</th>
                  <th className="py-2 px-4 border-b">Severity</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {filteredIssues.map((issue, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">{index + 1}</td>
                    <td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">{issue.message}</td>
                    <td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">{issue.linter}</td>
                    <td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">{issue.file}</td>
                    <td className="py-2 px-4 border-b">{issue.severity}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Issues);

const clients = new Set();

app.get('/api/events', (req, res) => {
    console.log('New client connected to SSE');
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });
    
    const client = res;
    clients.add(client);
    
    req.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected from SSE');
        clients.delete(client);
    });

    client.write('data: {"message": "Connected"}\n\n');
});

app.post('/api/build-complete', (req, res) => {
    const { buildNumber, result } = req.body;
    console.log(`Build ${buildNumber} completed with result: ${result}`);
    
    const eventData = JSON.stringify({ buildNumber, result });
    clients.forEach(client => {
        client.write(`data: ${eventData}\n\n`);
    });
    console.log(`Sent build completion event to ${clients.size} clients`);
    
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/api/trigger-pipeline', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Received trigger pipeline request:', req.body);
    try {
        const { repoName, githubUsername } = req.body;
        
        if (!repoName || !githubUsername) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing repoName or githubUsername' });
        }

        console.log('Triggering Jenkins pipeline for repo:', repoName, 'and GitHub username:', githubUsername);

        const response = await axios.post(
            `${JENKINS_URL}/job/generate-issues/buildWithParameters`,
            `REPO_URL=https://github.com/${githubUsername}/${repoName}.git`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': JENKINS_AUTH,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
        );

        console.log('Jenkins response:', response.status, response.data);
        res.json({ message: 'Pipeline triggered successfully', status: response.status });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error triggering pipeline:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to trigger pipeline', details: error.message });
    }
});

app.get('/api/build-status', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${JENKINS_URL}/job/generate-issues/lastBuild/api/json`, {
            headers: { 'Authorization': JENKINS_AUTH }
        });
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching build status:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch build status' });
    }
});

app.get('/api/megalinter-logs/:buildNumber', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { buildNumber } = req.params;
        const response = await axios.get(
            `${JENKINS_URL}/job/generate-issues/${buildNumber}/artifact/megalinter-reports/megalinter.log`,
            {
                headers: { 'Authorization': JENKINS_AUTH }
            }
        );
        res.send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching MegaLinter logs:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch MegaLinter logs' });
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

